# How to check ACTION_SEND intent is started?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-testing

My app uses standard simple sharing of text. In my test I want to check that my activity started the sharing intent. Is it possible?

I am using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` test.

Activity:

```
final Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share"));
```

Test:

```
final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentFilter.addDataType("text/plain");
final ActivityMonitor receiverActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(
            intentFilter, null, false);

TouchUtils.clickView(this, getActivity().findViewById(R.id.share_button));
final Activity shareActivity = receiverActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(500);
assertNotNull(shareActivity); // Fails
```

The above test does not work. Is there a way to test that ACTION_SEND intent has started?

### Temporary solution

For now, in activity I am saving intent to a member variable:

```
mSendIntent = new Intent();
```

So I can verify it from test:

```
assertEquals("android.intent.action.SEND", getActivity().mSharingIntent.getAction());
assertEquals("text/plain", getActivity().mSharingIntent.getType());
String sharedText = getActivity().mSharingIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
assertEquals("test I shared", sharedText);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the result of `Intent.createChooser` to `startActivity`, so you need to monitor `Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER` action.

```
final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
final ActivityMonitor receiverActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(intentFilter, null, false);

TouchUtils.clickView(this, getActivity().findViewById(R.id.share_button));
final Activity shareActivity = receiverActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(500);
assertNotNull(shareActivity);
```

Comment: hi @Sundrique. Sorry to post here, but I'm trying to do the same, but instead use `TouchUtils.clickView` I'm using `onView(allOf(withText(R.string.report_issues))).perform(click());` and I my `shareActivity` is always null. Did this behavior is linked to the fact I'm using `onview.perform` instead using `TouchUtils`?

Comment: Hi @LuizE. Are you sure you use correct intent action? Can you see a chooser displayed when you run your test case on emulator or device?