# Android testing: how to test that createChooser was opened

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium

My App have a share option and I'm trying to test if the "Choose an App to share" activity was opened. I can see it opening on my tablet, but it's not being catched by my test. Already tried several possible ways, including the suggestion posted here

[How to check ACTION_SEND intent is started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178133/how-to-check-action-send-intent-is-started)

but nothing seems to work. Please help me in figuring out what is wrong.
Thanks!

Activity:

```
Intent intencao = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
intencao.setType("text/plain");
intencao.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Horários de ônibus offline em NH");
String strAux = "Experimente esse App\n\n";
strAux += "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.solenoide.onibus \n\n";
intencao.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strAux);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intencao, "Escolha como compartilhar"));
```

Test:

```
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    solo.unlockScreen();
    View menuItem = atividade.findViewById(br.com.solenoide.onibus.R.id.action_compartilhar);

    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
    final ActivityMonitor receiverActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(intentFilter, null, true);

    solo.clickOnActionBarItem(menuItem.getId());
    final Activity shareActivity = receiverActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(1000);
    assertNotNull(shareActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [this](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-unit-testing.html):

```
final Intent launchIntent = getStartedActivityIntent();
assertNotNull("Intent was null", launchIntent);

final String payload =
        launchIntent.getStringExtra(NextActivity.EXTRAS_PAYLOAD_KEY);
assertEquals("Payload is empty", LaunchActivity.STRING_PAYLOAD, payload);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't worked. I think it's because my Activity is extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, instead of ActivityUnitTestCase. If I simply extend ActivityUnitTestCase, Eclipse won't start the test! The last message I get from console is "Sending test information to Eclipse", the % progress at the bottom right corner stays at 100% for a long time, and the test never starts. Is there another way to do this extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Comment: getStartedActivityIntent gives me a syntax error. It is only available when I extend the Activity to ActivityUnitTestCase.

Comment: I never used Eclipse for testing because Android Studio was published a long time ago. Try to change your IDE to Android Studio.